# Create MasterPage programmatically in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-365, office

I want to create custom master page and page layout using visual studio. I have already created these in SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 in farm solution and Sandbox solution in 2010(for office 365).

Now in 2013 sandbox solution are deprecated. Then how to do that? Can we create using app?

One more point to create sandbox solution we need AD, Sql and sharepoint should be installed on different server (3 layer architecture). If we do not have 3 layer architecture and we only have single farm where everything is installed on one server. In that case how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No-code Sandbox Solution (NCSS) aren't deprecated. Only custom code in sandbox solution is deprecated: 
[Deprecation of Custom Code in Sandboxed Solutions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx)

You can then still use a Sandbox solution that has only declarative Elements such as master pages, and page layouts, provisioned by modules.

If you want to move away from Sandbox solutions, and approach the Add-in model as much as possible (right choice ;)) I suggest you to look at this sample, which should be very similar to your needs

***Summary***
This sample demonstrates common tasks related on the publishing features, like how to deploy page layouts and master pages. It also shows how you can use property bag entries in the Web object to control the available page layouts and available web templates settings for the publishing sites.

[Branding.ApplyBranding (OfficeDev/PnP)](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Branding.ApplyBranding)